# how can I see a submodule reflected in a project on github?

Tags: git, github

I am keeping class notes for a class with no certifications on GitHub, in the hopes that the details I provide can act as some record of my work. A class I am taking has me forking a project they have on GitHub, so I already have this as a separate GitHubproject.
I need it to show up in my records for the class, so I thought a good way to do it was to create the folder as a submodule of the class project.

This works just fine. On my filesystem I see it created the folder, updated, and my project is there. However, it is not added to my project, and git dekstop says that I **cannot** add the submodule to my class project. The result is that the folder of my class notes has no record, not even a link pointing to my fork which is on GitHub.

I'd like to rectify that.
How can I get that submodule to show up in some way, without relying on a simple (but in this case awkward) markdown link in the wiki or readme pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2016: Whenever Git Desktop GUI doesn't provide the expected service, revert back to the command line (open a shell)

Make sure there is nothing  tracked in your class project representing your github fork, and then type:

```
cd /path/class_project
git submodule add -- https://github.com/<user>/<yourFork>
git add .
git commit -m "add yourFork" as submodule
git push
```

---

Update oct. 2022, 6 years later!

> ### [GitHub Desktop improves submodule support and now supports multi-commit diffing](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-04-github-desktop-improves-submodule-support-and-now-supports-multi-commit-diffing) (Oct. 2022)
>
> GitHub Desktop 3.1 improves submodule support and now supports multi-commit diffing.
>
> Submodule support just got much better from GitHub Desktop by providing a more detailed “diff” when they have changes.
> You will now know whether submodules are just pointing at a different commit or if there are changes within them that you must commit.
> You can also open the submodule at the click of a button!
>
> [image: https://i0.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/1083228/192795119-c7029824-8920-47a8-b675-e682803fbf3d.png?ssl=1 -- Screenshot of GitHub Desktop displaying a submodule diff]
>
> You can now also see all the changes across multiple commits by just selecting them.
> That way, you can be certain about the changes you’re about to push or merge onto another branch, and make sure no unintended changes are included in them.
>
> [image: https://i0.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/1083228/192795125-bf0a17a7-591a-4a28-9763-4d831c75325e.png?ssl=1 -- Screenshot of GitHub Desktop displaying multi-commit diffs]
>
> [Learn more about GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com)

Comment: I'm amazed that all I needed to do was manually add it. Why on earth would github desktop not work to add a change if "add ." is all it needs to do? Anyway, that worked. thank you